# Python 3 BS4 - Extract Data from <span> tags

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract data from span tags in an HTML page.

the HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="DataInSpanTags">
   <span>data1</span>
   <span>data2</span>
   <span>data3</span>
</div>
```

I have used the following script to extract:

```
for TagGrab in soup.find_all('div', class_='DataInSpanTags'):
MoreStats = TagGrab.span.text
print(MoreStats)
```

This only returns the value from the first span tag 'Data1'.

Is there a way to grab the rest on the data?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: From what i have googled it is an inline block span

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose there is only one `<div class="DataInSpanTags">` you are interested in, so after finding it with `.find('div', class_='DataInSpanTags')` you need to find all the `span` tags inside it using `.findAll('span')`:

```
>>> for span in soup.find('div', class_='DataInSpanTags').findAll('span'):
...     print(span.text)
... 
data1
data2
data3
```

Comment: Thank you for this. It worked. There are more of these throughout the HTML page with different info. Can I grab all the 'DataInSpanTags' and retrieve the information from each one?

Comment: Sure! Just use `for data in soup.findAll('DataInSpanTags'): for span in data.findAll('span'): print(span.text)`. Please remember to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) the answer if it was helpful, it's an overall good for the community.